# Azure - Can we use Service Management API to create/update/Delete Resource with XAMPP Localhost?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

Can we use Service Management API to create/update/Delete Resource with XAMPP Localhost? They seek Certificates .cer and .pfx. I have uplaoded under Azure panel and unser my service -> SSL Settings.

When I am trying to make a connection from my local machine for Service API it still giving me exception Certificate not found. I am using PHP SDK for Azure. [package : "microsoft/windowsazure": "^0.5"]

can someone please guide me how to make conneciton from local and what if I want to make it in production?

Answer (score 0):

Was using wrong format of certificates, it needs .pem file absolute path. .cer must have to be imported under your Subscription Management certificates in Azure portal